# How to create a two way connection for a range of cells

Tags: vba, connection

I found the code to make a 2-way connection for a single cell on 2 different worksheets and it works perfectly. I can add a value to either and it changes it in the other to be the same. But instead of just doing it for a single cell, I tried entering a range of cells (example: "A4:A100") and I get the following error when it reaches the 2nd line of code:
Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

OK just added the following to my original message. First is the code I was referring that creates a 2-way update for a single field:

---

IN SHEET 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B7")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target = Range("B7") Then
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value <> Target.Value Then
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = Target.Value
    End If
  End If
End If

End Sub
```

IN SHEET 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B7")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target = Range("B7") Then
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value <> Target.Value Then
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = Target.Value
    End If
  End If
End If

End Sub
```

---

This code works perfect for a single cell.  But what if I wanted to do this same thing for an entire range of cells?  For example, instead of just Cell A4, what if I wanted this feature for cells A4:A100?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code in a code block so we can read it and try to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *I found the code to make a 2-way connection for a single cell on 2 different worksheets and it works perfectly. I can add a value to either and it changes it in the other to be the same.* Provide this code.

Comment: Thanks you. I just updated my original post with the code I was referring to, and at the bottom I re-stated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to be very specific with your questions. For example, you could've said some of the things I'm identifying here. (The idea is to do the leg-work yourself so the person answering doesn't have to guess, or type it all out, or ask questions.)

I see your code is the same for Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Maybe that wasn't intentional, because it would've been easier for you and me if you only pasted it once, and you didn't mention it was the same.

• Is that intentional? If so...

I see currently Cell `A4` on Sheet 1 gets updated by `B7` of either Sheet, whereas Cell `A4` on Sheet 2 gets updated by nothing.

You didn't actually say what the code does when it works perfectly. You said "make a 2-way connection for a single cell on 2 different worksheets" but a "2-way connection" could mean various things. See what I mean?

• So was my description what yours is doing when it's working perfectly? If so...

When I replace `A4` with `A4:A100` in all locations, I get the `Type mismatch` error on Line 5, which is the 4th line of code not including spacers, and is the 3rd line of code not including spacers nor the `Sub` prototype line, so technically I couldn't reproduce your error related to the 2nd line of code.

• Is that the error you meant? If so...

You said you may want "this feature" to apply to a range of cells, but what does "this feature" mean to you exactly? What is it doing now versus what do you want it to do when it applies to a range?

• Do you just want it to display the value from `B7` of either Sheet over the whole range `A4:A100` on Sheet 1? If so...

This solution works well for me when it's in both sheets:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B7")) Is Nothing Then
      If Target = Range("B7") Then
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value <> Target.Value Then
          Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:A100").Value = Target.Value
        End If
      End If
    End If

End Sub
```

The difference between getting a mismatch error and the solution is...

`If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:100").Value <> Target.Value Then` versus

`If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value <> Target.Value Then` respectively.

The error is because of a bit of a gotcha in VBA. We can assign a value to a range, but we can't get it for concatenation or evaluation. It makes some sense if you think about it like this: When Excel assigns to a range, it's clear which value or values it should assign to -- all of them. But when it reads a value from a range, which one should it read? The first, the last? It doesn't want to assume, and it doesn't want to check every value to make sure they're all the same because it could be millions of cells.

So the solution was to tell it which one cell's value, the first cell, `A4` to compare with the single value of `Target`. Yes, `Target` is technically Range too, but that range is guaranteed to be one cell in this context, so we can get it's one value without Excel having to assume anything.

And that's safe in terms of "logic errors" (versus "compile errors" and "runtime errors") because we know there will never be different values in the cells of `A4:100` at the same time or we accept the fact that only the value of `A4` matters for whether or not to update.

Depending on exactly why you're checking things (or how much you might be relying on copy+paste from existing solutions) it may interest you to know that this is also a solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B7")) Is Nothing Then
          Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:A100").Value = Target.Value
    End If

End Sub
```